# Number of Active Sessions Google Colab Pro

Tags: google-colaboratory

The free version of Google Colab is limited in the number of active sessions that can be running at the same time. For example, I can only train two ML models at the same time.

I wanted to know if Google Colab Pro extends the number of available active sessions such that I can train multiple models at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yup, the limit in Colab Pro is higher. Presently, you can use 4 standard GPU backends and 4 high-memory GPU backends concurrently.

Comment: So does it mean total 8 sessions concurrently?

Comment: It may change from time-to-time. For the past week, my experience has been 3 GPUs total (high-ram vs standard). I have two Colab Pros, and so that gives me six total simultaneous runs right now.

Comment: well, right now with colab pro, it seems I can only run one standard GPU and one high-memory GPU backends. I think it depends on the actual demand